# Docusign sign in person Action is not visible.

Tags: docusignapi

Docusign sign in person Action is not visible.

I am trying to implement **sign in person** docusign feature

but this option is not available.

[image]

Any idea how to enable this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The checkbox to enable/disable Enable In Person Signing on an account is available under preferences -> features in the DocuSign web app/console. If you are unable to enable it yourself, please escalate this to DocuSign support so they can do this on your behalf (under the assumption your account/subscription includes this functionality).

Comment: Yes this is the issue I already raised a case to DocuSign support. Thanks for confirming..